# Lasso ||a|| and "General Lasso" ||Da||

Tags: lasso, algorithms, regularization

Ryan Tibshirani introduced once a more general type of Lasso, where the regularizer is
$$\parallel D \alpha \parallel_1$$
instead of $\parallel \alpha \parallel_1$.
[See paper](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~ryantibs/papers/genlasso.pdf)

However, there is nearly no discussion about this form and I wonder why since its a great way to deal with derivative smoothness regularizers.

- Is there an easy way I overlooked  to transform a general Lasso to the standard Lasso form?
- Which algorithm can be used for the gen. lasso? Currently I only tested quadratic programs, but this is quite slow.

Comment: The main topic of that paper you linked to is answering the two bullets in your question!  The answers are: 1) in general no, and 2) yes, but it's generally slower than algorithms for the standard lasso.  See another paper by Ryan Tibshirani for an application to "derivative smoothness" regularization: http://arxiv.org/abs/1304.2986

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much for the hint to the paper! Looks very interesting. I will definitely take a close look on it.
As for the General Lasso Form, I ended up using the "split bregman" method to compute the solution of a "general lasso" problem. In most cases it is much faster then a quadratic program.

Comment: Add "Is there an easy way I overlooked to transform a general Lasso to the standard Lasso form?" - am I wrong in thinking that using `D=diag(1,p)` (a diagonal matrix with 1 values on diagonal) leads to a starndard Lasso form?

Comment: @Marta, yes, but you dont choose D usually. Its set by the applicaiton. When D is not diagonal, then its not a standard Lasso.:)

Answer (score 1):

Partially answered in comments:

The main topic of that paper you linked to is answering the two bullets in your question! The answers are: 1) in general no, and 2) yes, but it's generally slower than algorithms for the standard lasso. See another paper by Ryan Tibshirani for an application to "derivative smoothness" regularization: https://arxiv.org/abs/1304.2986 – vqv

( Wow! Thank you so much for the hint to the paper! Looks very interesting. I will definitely take a close look on it. As for the General Lasso Form, I ended up using the "split bregman" method to compute the solution of a "general lasso" problem. In most cases it is much faster then a quadratic program. – mojovski )